# How do I display multiple kable tables in a m x n grid?

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I have 6 tables and I want them to display 3 x 2 in a grid. I have been using Kable to display my tables, which has worked fairly well for me, but when I pass tables into kables as a list it only displays them horizontally.

As an example using the following code:

```
t1 <- mtcars[1:3,]
t2 <- mtcars[4:6,]
t3 <- mtcars[7:9,]
t4 <- mtcars[10:12,]
t5 <- mtcars[13:15,]
t6 <- mtcars[16:18,]
kable(list(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6)) %>% kable_styling()
```

All 6 tables go horizontally in a row. Is there a way to stack these 3 x 2 on top of each other?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a combination of `kable` from the `knitr` package and `kableExtra` functionalities.

First, for each row, we can combine the tables horizontally using `kable` and `pack_rows`. Then, we combine the rows vertically.

Here's an example I got:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

t1 <- mtcars[1:3,]
t2 <- mtcars[4:6,]
t3 <- mtcars[7:9,]
t4 <- mtcars[10:12,]
t5 <- mtcars[13:15,]
t6 <- mtcars[16:18,]

# Create individual tables
k1 <- kable(t1, caption = "t1", format = "html") %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped"))
k2 <- kable(t2, caption = "t2", format = "html") %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped"))
k3 <- kable(t3, caption = "t3", format = "html") %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped"))
k4 <- kable(t4, caption = "t4", format = "html") %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped"))
k5 <- kable(t5, caption = "t5", format = "html") %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped"))
k6 <- kable(t6, caption = "t6", format = "html") %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped"))

# Combine horizontally for each row
row1 <- cbind(k1, k2) %>% kable_styling()
row2 <- cbind(k3, k4) %>% kable_styling()
row3 <- cbind(k5, k6) %>% kable_styling()

# Combine rows vertically
grid <- rbind(row1, row2, row3)

grid
```

This approach should arrange the tables in a 3x2 grid. The styling and bootstrap options are just for illustration purposes, you can adjust them as needed.